# Finding the optimal straight line boundary

Tags: integer, matrix, optimization, fastest-algorithm

Consider an \$n \times n\$ grid of integers. The task is to draw a straight line across the grid so that the part that includes the top left corner sums to the largest number possible.  Here is a picture of an optimal solution with score 45:

[image]

We include a square in the part that is to be summed if its middle is above or on the line. Above means in the part including the top left corner of the grid. (To make this definition clear, no line can start exactly in the top left corner of the grid.)

The task is to choose the line that maximizes the sum of the part that includes the top left square. The line must go straight from one side to another. The line can start or end anywhere on a side and not just at integer points.

The winning criterion is worst case time complexity as a function of \$n\$. That is using big Oh notation, e.g. \$O(n^4)\$.

## Test cases

I will add more test cases here as I can.

The easiest test cases are when the input matrix is made of positive (or negative) integers only. In that case a line that makes the part to sum the whole matrix (or the empty matrix if all the integers are negative) wins.

Only slightly less simple is if there is a line that clearly separates the negative integers from the non negative integers in the matrix.

Here is a slightly more difficult example with an optimal line shown. The optimal value is 14.

[image]

The grid in machine readable form is:

```
[[ 3 -1 -2 -1]
 [ 0  1 -1  1]
 [ 1  1  3  0]
 [ 3  3 -1 -1]]
```

Here is an example with optimal value 0.

[image]

```
[[-3 -3  2 -3]
 [ 0 -2 -1  0]
 [ 1  0  2  0]
 [-1 -2  1 -1]]
```

Posted a question to [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/53674/is-there-a-lower-bound-for-the-problem-of-finding-the-best-straight-line-partiti) about lower bounds for this problem.

Comment: Must the line end at integer?

Comment: @l4m2 No, although a fast algorithm for that case would be really interesting too.

Comment: What determines the value in each cell? Is it just arbitrary data given as input to the function?

Comment: @SteveBennett Yes it is arbitrary data given as input to the function. You can assume they will be integers in a sensible range, say -2^16 to 2^16.

Comment: I can't think of an approach that is better than O(n^4). There are O(n^2) meaningfully distinct directions of the line (the number of slopes = 2 + 2 * number of distinct x/y where 1<=x,y<n = [A002088](https://oeis.org/A002088)(n-1) = asymptotically n^2). For each slope, as the line moves in one direction, the points will be included one at a time. You need to account for every single partition made with the slope, so it is O(n^2) per slope, giving O(n^4) in total. Maaaaaaybe one can deduplicate the partitions, but I doubt the count is asymptotically lower.

Comment: @Bubbler maybe you can sort the slopes, and maintain the order you include the points (in some data structure). However, from some back-of-the-envelope calculations the amount of changes there is still \$O(n^4)\$, so it doesn't seem that helpful. Maybe if you can somehow do this maintenance in bulk it could work, but I don't see a way to do that

Comment: It's worth noting the relation with [Euclid's orchard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_orchard). The "meaningful directions" @Bubbler mentions are all the `(dx, dy)` where `dx`, `dy` are coprimes. There are (n^2 * 6/π^2) of them on average, i.e. ~61% of n^2. Not a big improvement but at least one can avoid duplicated slopes.

Comment: @PierreD Can you see how to code up this improvement?

Comment: Sure, see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: BTW, when I have time, I've been thinking about a branch-and-bound algorithm that _might possibly_ save some exploration time (on average, but not on the worst case). I have no definite idea of how much of the computation can be avoided. I'll post probably on the SO question rather than here if I get to it and it's successful. If I get to it and it's not successful, I'll let you know as well, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Python3, O(n^4):

I'm not 100% sure this is correct, but I think at least the approach is solid and it seems to work OK.

```py
import numpy as np
import fractions

def best_line(grid):
    n, m = grid.shape
    D = [(di, dj) for di in range(-(n - 1), n) for dj in range(-(n - 1), n)]
    def slope(d):
        di, dj = d
        if dj == 0:
            return float('inf') if di <= 0 else float('-inf'), -di
        else:
            return fractions.Fraction(di, dj), fractions.Fraction(-1, dj)
    D.sort(key=slope)
    D = np.array(D, dtype=np.int64)
    s_max = grid.sum()
    for grid in (grid, grid.T):
        left_sum = 0
        for j in range(grid.shape[1]):
            left_sum += grid[:,j].sum()
            for i in range(grid.shape[0]):
                p = np.array([i, j], dtype=np.int64)
                Q = p + D
                Q = Q[np.all((0 <= Q) & (Q < np.array(grid.shape)), axis=1)]
                s = left_sum 
                for q in Q:
                    if not np.any(q):
                        break
                    if q[1] <= j:
                        s -= grid[q[0],q[1]]
                    else:
                        s += grid[q[0],q[1]]
                    s_max = max(s_max, s)
    return s_max
```

Comment: Can you explain the method?

Comment: @Simd It spins a line around each grid point, incrementally adding and removing points as it crosses them.

Comment: I am impressed that method gives the optimal solution for my 10 by 10 problem now given in the question. I wonder where it is drawing the line.

Comment: Sounds it work correctly but I feel it not optimal complexity

Comment: Do you think it would be faster if lines had to start/end at integer points?

Comment: @Simd Not in terms of complexity, It's basically the same problem. You can take any line and move it until it's almost touching 2 grid points, without changing the sum.

Comment: That is what I feared. I wonder if \$O(n^4)\$ is really optimal.

Comment: How can I get your code to output the line that is found as well?

Comment: In the code for `D` (the slopes), you can avoid duplicates (there should be about 39% of them where `dx, dy` are not coprime). Doesn't change the _O()_ of course.

Comment: @PierreD I think you need the duplicates in case the optimal line cuts across a given slope.

Comment: You shouldn't need duplicates. The slope `(2,3)` is the same as the `(4,6)` one. In `D` above, those two will be next to each other after sorting. For a quick test, you can replace `D` by: `D = [(sdi, sdj) for di in range(1, n) for dj in range(1, n) if gcd(di, dj) == 1 for sdi in [-di, di] for sdj in [-dj, dj]]`. But for (much) better performance in generating coprimes up to a large `n`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737356/758174).

Comment: @PierreD Oh, I see what you mean. It won't speed up the main loop though, so any performance difference will be minor.

Comment: Could you explain how to output the optimal line from the code please? I tried saving i, j and q but that doesn't give a sensible answer. E.g. https://bpa.st/7BMA